# Segmentation Fault outside the loop only

Tags: c, linux, loops, segmentation-fault, dynamic-allocation

Using C on Linux, I'm writing a code that stores all the information about the files in a directory using function stat() and prints them on the Terminal
The algorithm is quite simple, I made a structure array of "files" and dynamically allocated them. The structure contains a char array (string) so I dynamically allocated it too.
The thing is .. the dynamic allocation works fine but if I'm inside the while loop I can access the other element inside the structure - which is a structure stat object - but if I access it after the loop finishes, it gives me "Segmentation Fault"!
Here's the code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <dirent.h>
struct file{
    char* name;
    struct stat fbuf;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char* dir=NULL;
   int k;
   dir=(char *)malloc(strlen(argv[argc-1])+1);
   dir=argv[argc-1];
   strcpy(dir,argv[argc-1]);
   DIR *curr_dir;
   struct dirent *dir_inode;
   int i,j=0;
   char* sum=NULL;
   struct file* files=NULL;
   if ((curr_dir = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't  Open %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(2);
   }
    while (((dir_inode = readdir(curr_dir))) != NULL) {


    files=(struct file*) realloc(files,((j)+1)*(sizeof(char*)+sizeof(struct stat))); // Structure array reallocation    

    (files+(j))->name=(char *)(malloc(strlen(dir_inode->d_name)+1));//name allocation



    for(i=0;i<strlen(dir_inode->d_name);i++)
        (files+(j))->name[i]=dir_inode->d_name[i];//name storage
    (files+(j))->name[i]='\0';

    sum= (char *) malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(dir_inode->d_name)+2);//To add file name to its directory

    for(i=0;i<strlen(dir);i++)
        sum[i]=dir[i];

    sum[i]='/';
    i++;
    for(k=0;dir_inode->d_name[k]!='\0';k++)
        sum[i+k]=dir_inode->d_name[k];
    sum[i+k]='\0';//file name with directory in sum


    if( stat(sum,&((files+j)->fbuf)) == -1){ // the function gets information from the file name and stores them in fbuf
        printf("error stat\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    free(sum);
            if(    S_ISDIR(  (  (files+(j))->fbuf  ).st_mode  )    ){
             printf("d");
            }
            else {
               printf("-");
            }
//Here the output appears fine
//The output depends on accessing fbuf in files array
                            printf("statOK\n");
    (j)++; // index
    } 
                            printf("%d %d %d\n",files,j,files+1);



                            printf("%d\n",j);





   printf("\n\n\n\n");
   for(i=0;i<j;i++){
      printf("%s\n",(files+i)->name);
      printf("%d\n",files);
    //Starting from here, same syntax but outside the loop it gives the error
      if(    S_ISDIR(  (  (files+i)->fbuf  ).st_mode  )    ){
         printf("d");

      else {
         printf("-");
      }
}
free(files);
free(dir);
closedir(curr_dir);
exit(1);

}
```

The code isn't complete yet but all what I want is to access the fbuf outside the loop, then I can complete it
Any ideas?

Comment: `strcpy(dir,argv[argc-1])` needs to be changed to `dir = argv[argc-1]`, since dir is a heap allocated pointer

Comment: Changed it .. Still same error :/

Comment: Please fix up your code formatting. It's impossible to read at the moment. But more importantly there is a missing closing braces near the end of the code. The placing of that closing braces may or may not be significant.

Comment: What happens when you hard-code the values in `files`, instead of relying on command-line arguments and the file system? *Simplify.*

Comment: The assignment is to simulate the command-line arguments :)

Answer (score 2):

## Bad size assumption

This allocation is wrong:

> ```
> files=(struct file*) realloc(files,((j)+1)*(sizeof(char*)+sizeof(struct stat)));
> ```

Here, you assumed that the size of `struct file` was the sum of the sizes of its two components.  But in fact, you don't know how that structure is packed and aligned, so the size of `struct file` could be larger than what you thought.  You should just be using `sizeof(struct file)` instead:

```
files=(struct file*) realloc(files,(j+1)*(sizeof(struct file)));
```